# MS Teams Call Queue - Wait time

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, call-queue

How do I get the time a call waited in MS Teams Call Queue before answered by an agent?

Any suggestions will help!

Thanks

Comment: You need to look at the call overflow handling. Maximum calls in the queue specifies the maximum number of calls that can wait in the queue at any given time. The default is 50, but it can range from 0 to 200. When this limit is reached, the call is handled as specified by the When the maximum number of calls is reached setting. You can choose to disconnect the call or redirect it to one of the call routing destinations. For example, you might have the caller leave a voicemail for the agents in queue.

refer: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/create-a-phone-system-call-queue

Comment: I'm looking for a way to see how much time the caller wait in the queue (not in real-time - like a history log)

Comment: AFAIK, i dont remember a way exists at this point. So i would suggest you to file a feature request with Microsoft using their uservoice, so that they can consider it. Here's the link - https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public

Comment: Currently getting the call wait time for user is not available please raise a uservoice for this